# Grand theft auto V has exited unexpectedly (after notebook fix update)

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, windows-7

For some reason my GTA V still keeps crashing even after the update which should "fix" the problem with 2 graphics cards.

Also when I try to run only with my Intel/AMD graphics card it ends up giving an error that DirectX 9 wasn't found on my device? Which I get for my Intel but not my AMD. It has to be installed on at least one of them cause it doesn't give this error with both enabled.

Specs:
i7 4700MQ
AMD HD8970m
8GB of ram
Windows 7 64 bit

My GTA is installed on a hdd and there is over 400gb of space left. I also tried repairing my files with the uninstaller you can also repair your game there instead of uninstalling.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you have both cards enabled in device manager?

Comment: yes I do I tried one at a time and running it with the other but this kept giving the directx 9 error. Also I would like to know why my post got closed? This question was asked before the "fix" update wich didn't work for me so I asked it for other users who still have the same problem at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Reopened.

Comment: so, when you're running with both cards enabled, what error are you getting?

Comment: What update is this? The one update I know about is 1.01, which doesn't mention fixing this problem in its patch notes.

Comment: @cpast I just checked the patch notes and you're right, it's not mentioned anywhere. However, a lot of people (including myself) report no more launcher crashing with both gpu's enabled, so it would be nice to figure out if some people are having the same issue, or it's a different problem, but they think it's the same issue.

Comment: @Chipples I'm still having the problem.

Comment: @cpast Allright I read on another question that this patch did fix the problem so I'm actually happy they didn't really mention the fix yet. I hope they are still working on it then so I can play this game sometime....

Comment: @Chippies Also the error I'm getting is "Grand theft auto V has exited unexpectedly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this for real check my new video

Comment: It would be best to summarize what's in the video too if you can. Youtube Videos can be taken down without warning and without anything more that the video itself to answer the question your answer will be invalidated should that happen

Comment: It works for me but gta stays in power saving mode when it launches and I put it back on performance. Its just way too slow and unplayable with this solution for me.

Comment: I can play it okay just stuttering a bit when im driving fast for me although I think im running on my amd 2 gb card though with performance being the last setting I enabled not sure though.

Comment: I think I have to wait for the actual fix from rockstar games :( Got a 4gb graphics card so it shouldn't be lagging so badly on 1920x1080 on the lowest graphics settings. I was only able to play normally on 800x600 (looks even worse then san andreas)